# Show that there is no polynomials $P,Q$ such that $\pi(n)=\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Show that there is no polynomials $P,Q$ such that $\pi(n)=\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}$ for an infinity many $n$.

**Attempts**

Let $(n_k)$ a sequence s.t. $\pi(n_k)=\frac{P(n_k)}{Q(n_k)}$ and suppose by contradiction that $\#\{n_k\}=\infty $. Since $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\pi(n_k)=\infty ,$$
we have that $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\frac{P(n_k)}{Q(n_k)}=\infty,$$
and thus $\deg P>\deg Q$. Let $m=\deg P$ and $\ell=\deg Q$. We suppose WLOG that $P$ and $Q$ are monic. Since $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials,
$$\frac{P(n_k)}{Q(n_k)}\sim n_k^{m-\ell}.$$
By Tchebychev, $$\pi(n_k)\ll \frac{n_k}{\log(n_k)},$$
and thus $$n_k^{m-\ell}\ll \frac{n_k}{\log(n_k)}$$
and thus $m-\ell< 1$. That implies that $\ell\geq m$ what is a contradiction.

Is this proof fine ? Is there easier ?

Comment: What is $\pi(n)$? Is $\pi$ a function?

Comment: @Bemte: As usual in number theory ;-)  $\pi(x)=\#\{p\leq x\mid p\ prime\}$.

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ are in : $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Comment: I don't think it's true that you can assume WLOG that $P$ and $Q$ are monic. All this does is introduce a constant factor, and this doesn't affect the validity of your argument. Also, I'm not familiar with the double inequality symbol you use. Depending on what the precise statement of "Tchebychev" you're appealing to is, this approach seems to work.

Comment: @J.OK: in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Comment: @user49640: Thank you. I write $f\ll g$ to denote $f=\mathcal O(g)$. I supposed that $P$ and $Q$ are monic because if not we will have just the result up to a constant and this doesn't change the result in the $\mathcal O$.

Comment: I don't think that's a proper use of WLOG. Because it's not as though you've logically reduced the general case to the case where that's true. You've just said that it changes little in the proof.